# Multiple Instance of task can be seen after fixing task hijacking issue

Tags: android, security

Applications running on android devices below 10 are vulnerable to task hijacking. Even though the issue is fixed from android 11 and above, we cannot tell our customers to upgrade the android version in order to fix the issue.

Some recommendations I found were to use taskaffinity="" and to use single instance activities. However, doing so is breaking the user experience by creating a separate task window that shows up as two different applications in the recent task list.

Is there any official statement from Google regarding how this can be mitigated in devices running Android 10 and below?